# Get the POINT in middle of Down arrow of vScroll on Wireshark PacketList window

Tags: python, wireshark, pywinauto

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# # myGUI7.py   # use pywinauto to start Wireshark
# Visual Studio Code is Run as Administrator 

import os
import sys

import pywinauto 
from pywinauto.application import Application

# which PyQt5 is needed to be imported?
#from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
#from PyQt5.QtGui import *
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractSlider

def process_GUI(pname, fname): 
    # start Wireshark -- it uses Qt5, ergo backend = uia
    app = Application(backend="uia").start(r"C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\Wireshark.exe ")
    if app.SoftwareUpdate.exists(timeout=5):
        app.SoftwareUpdate.SkipThisVersion.click()
        app.SoftwareUpdate.Wait_Not('visible') #make sure it is closed
    ##app['The Wireshark Network Analyzer'].print_control_identifiers()

    # open any pcapng file
    win = app["The Wireshark Network Analyzer"]
    win.wait('ready', timeout=5)
    win.type_keys('%F{ENTER}') # Alt+F, Enter (it calls "&File->&Open" menu)
    app.Dialog2.FilenameEdit.set_edit_text(pname + fname)
    app.Dialog2.Open4.click()
    win = app[fname]
    win.wait('ready', timeout=5)
    ##win.print_control_identifiers()

    # get the Packet list window
    PL = win["Packet list"]  # it is a TreeView object  
 
    # how do I get the POINT in middle of Down arrow of vScroll on PL?

# = = = = = = =
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # use path/file of any pcapng that has been saved
    path_name = "C:\\H_Paul\\ws\\"
    file_name = "ws-aug22a_SOsample.pcapng"
    guiReturn = process_GUI(path_name, file_name)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to scroll down Packet List, you can use

```
# workaround for set_focus() failure on uia backend
app_win32 = Application(backend="win32").connect(path=r"wireshark.exe")
app_win32.window(best_match='Qt5QWindowIcon').set_focus()
PL.wheel_mouse_input(wheel_dist=-10) # negative wheel_dist means scroll down
```

or try `PL.type_keys('{VK_DOWN}')` to scroll Packet List.

The value of `IsScrollPatternAvailable` property of Packet List (QTreeView widget) is `false`, for this reason `PL.scroll("down", "line", 1)` cause error message "tree "Packet list" is not scrollable". Also inspect.exe doesn't show scrollbar among PacketList's children.

Also, you can try another approach: get bottom right coordinates of the Packet List, subtract (5,5) or other delta from them and click to this point. Something like (this code just demonstrates idea, because sends click to wrong coordinates on latest Wireshark version, which may be a Qt-related problem):

```
arrow_coords = (PL.rectangle().right - 5, PL.rectangle().bottom - 5)
for i in range(N):
    PL.click_input(coords=arrow_coords)
```

Comment: PL.type_keys('{VK_DOWN}') fails, with  -->C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py:415: RuntimeWarning: The window has not been focused due to COMError: (-2147220991, 'An event was unable to invoke any of the subscribers', (None, None, None, 0, None))
  warnings.warn('The window has not been focused due to ' \

Comment: I rechecked this and found out that `type_keys` approach only works if you open Wireshark window and click on the Packet List widget after script launch. I updated the answer and put the updated code (uses `wheel_mouse_input`) in it that works for me.

Comment: Try `PL.click_input(coords=arrow_coords, absolute=True)` because a rectangle is always returned in screen coordinates.